# Django Rest Framework view set url filter errors

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a backend using the django rest framework. I am building the defauly django user viewsets and urlpattern routers. I want to add a filter for the username in the url if there is a username passed in and if not, then show all the users. I will have my code below.

This is the views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ..serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username = username)
        return queryset
```

Here is the urls file:

```
from users.api.views.userViews import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'(?P<username>.+)/$', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

here is the urls in the settings:

```
path('api/users/', include('users.api.urls.userUrls')),
```

I want the following:

`api/users/` to return all users 
&
`api/users/testAdmin` to return the admin user object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for [**`lookup_field`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes) magic rather than a **`filter`**

Try the following code snippet,

```
# views.py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = User.objects.all()


# urls.py

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: is there a way to look up two different fields with one value passed into the url.. like a username that could be found in two fields. friender and friended....

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this in your view :

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    requested_user = self.kwargs.get('username')
    if (requested_user):
        qs = yourqueryset.objects.filter(User__username=requested_user)
    else:
        qs = yourqueryset.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    return qs
```